# Help for understanding greedy algorithm proof

Tags: algorithms, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I got the following problem: create a list containing exactly `a` zeros, `b` ones, `c` twos and `d` threes, where the absolute difference between two consecutivo numbers is exactly one. For seeing the original problem take a look here https://codeforces.com/contest/1265/problem/D.

The solution(and proof) provided by the authors is:

> Firstly, let's arrange even numbers. It is optimal to arrange those
>   numbers as 0,0,0,…,0,2,2,…2. Because we can place number 1 anywhere
>   while number 3 only between two numbers 2 or at the end beside a
>   number 2. So we need to maximize the number of positions where we can
>   place number 3. The above gives us an optimal way. The next step is to
>   place the remaining numbers 1,3. Inserting them in internal positions
>   first then at the ends later.

However I don't feel like this proof is enough for me. For example, `It is optimal to arrange those numbers`, there is no proof for that or I'm missing something.

Can someone please provide another proof or helping me to understand better this one.
Thanks in advance.